# How to mutate CSS custom property color with CSS-in-JS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, emotion, css-in-js

Suppose I have the following code with emotion's css`` prop:

```js
<div css={css`
  background: var(--bg);
`}>
```

But I would like to darken the background of this div.

Using sass this would be simple with the darken() function, but I don't think it is possible to use sass in emotion?

Another option would be to use a javascript darken function, e.g. like the one from polished.js:

```js
import { darken } from "polished";

<div css={css`
  background: ${darken(0.2, var(--bg))};
`}>
```

However, this is not possible either, since a CSS custom property like `var(--bg)` is not accessible in the javascript `${ }` scope.

Is there any simple, straightforward solution to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

For the `darken()` the closest I can think of is to use `brightness()` [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/brightness)

```
<div css={css`
  filter: brightness(80%);
`}>
```

Comment: I don't think that's the intended usage for the brightness() function. I've actually explored this a while ago, and it is very unpredictable in these cases. It definitely doesn't work in this case, since the background still needs to be set ...

Answer (score 0):

It can help ;)

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.body.style.setProperty('--color', 'blue')
})
```

```css
:root {
  --color: red;
}

body {
  background: var(--color)
}
```

```html
<button>TEST</button>
```

Comment: Yeah, this won't work either, since I don't want to assign a new color, I just want to darken the current color. With this solution I would have to manually pick a darkened color AOT everywhere I need to darken a color ...